# Displaying a random number in a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to display a random number in a label I created, but I have a syntax error.
Is there a way I can do this and show it in a label instead of `Console.Write`?

```
public partial class frmNumber : Form
{
    public frmNumber()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int RandomNumber()
    {
        int num; 
        Random random = new Random();
        num = random.Next(100);

        lblRandom.Text = num.ToString();
    }
    return num;
  // I have an error under return num;    
}
```

}

Comment: You need to move… `return num;` … into the `RandomNumber()` method. Above the “}” line.

Comment: looks like you have double } and one of them should be deleted and the return should be inside the method RandomNumber() method.

Comment: after moving the return num into the method, still, no number will appear.

Comment: You haven't called the method. This is similar to not starting your car and wondering why it won't go forward when you step on the gas pedal.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

Comment: ...also, you do not need to create a new Random object each time you call that method, and it may work against it working like you want.  Create one Random object and reuse it over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your method and you need to call it after InitializeComponent, otherwise, it is never called.

```
public frmNumber()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RandomNumber();
}

public void RandomNumber()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var num = random.Next(100);

    lblRandom.Text = num.ToString();
}
```

If you need also to return the number you can do it this way:

```
public frmNumber()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblRandom.Text = RandomNumber().ToString();
}

public int RandomNumber()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var num = random.Next(100);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: @LizaSarahG don't forget to mark this as the answer.